# string format for numbers or currency?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to give comma(,) for every thousends. So I used `DataFormatString="${0:#,#}"`. It is working fine. But when value is `0`. It is showing `$00`. I just want to show only `$0`.

How can we do that?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but as I keep forgetting the answer myself, the MSDN reference for all things string formatting is located here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Format = "${0:#,0}";

Comment: It would be useful to have some more details about this, like what is the actual output and what are some possible variations.

Answer (score 41):

```
DataFormatString = "{0:C0}"
```

That will format as a currency with 0 decimal places.

```
DataFormatString = "{0:N0}"
```

This will format as a number such as 1,000. If you want decimal places then replace the second 0 with however many numbers you want after the decimal.

For example:

```
DataFormatString = "{0:N4}"
```

Would format like 1,000.0000

Comment: It also has the benefit of using the current locale to get the correct currency symbol, thousands separator and decimal separator.

Comment: How can user for numbers? (not currency). I have {0:#,#} now it is show in 00 want it only 0

Comment: Where can we get this information? in MSDN> plz provide link.

Comment: `MyDecimal.ToString("{0:C3}")` doesn't work. Need to use `MyDecimal.ToString("C3")`. Tried to reverse downvote.