# Razor syntax - showing value without decimal point

Tags: razor

I have the following value returned to my razor view. The Property data type is Float in my model.

```
Model.Property: 1156.0
```

I am using following statement to convert it into currency format.

```
@string.Format("{0:C}", @Model.Property) USD
```

The current output is `$1,156.00 USD`

However, i am looking for output to be `$1,156 USD`

How i can acheive that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
@string.Format("{0:C0}", Model.Property) USD
```

The additional 0 denotes the number of decimal digits to display.

Comment: What if i want to do it from server side using Data Annotation. Do you have an idea?

Comment: You could decorate your property with the DIsplayFormat attribute `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]` and then use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Property)` to display it in your view.

Comment: It might be useful to point to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328130/string-format-for-numbers-or-currency) for those of you looking for a non-currency answer.